# Android Facebook SDK invalid fbid #100

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to share a link via FacebookDialog using Facebook SDK v3.18. I get this error while posting: (#100) invalid fbid. 
This is the code I used in my app:

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper; 
...  
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

...

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new     FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(HorizontalViewPagerCreator.this)
.setApplicationName("My app name")
.setLink("http://www.facebook.com")
.build();
 uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

This is the meta-data I added in my Manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```